# Flutter publising playstore error(soLoader)

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, google-play-console, hybrid-mobile-app

Hello i am getting this issue "Defective libraries
Your version of the SoLoader SDK is causing your app to crash for some users
" while i am trying to publish the flutter  app in playstore any one knows how to fix it?

Thanks in advance

I updated the fultter code and still not worked